# Remove/Edit feature definitions from AWS Sagemaker Feature Group

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, aws-feature-store

How do I edit/remove feature definitions (name/type) from my AWS Sagemaker Feature Group? From what I encounter in the Feature Store API, there are just options to delete Feature Group or record. I Tried to search the documentation for feature delete/edit methods without success. The current solution I see is to delete the Feature Group and recreate it with the correct feature definitions.

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker Feature Store supports the ability to delete an entire feature record, but not a specific feature. More specifically, the current version of Feature Store supports only immutable feature groups. Once you create a feature group, its schema cannot be changed.